# Characterization of closure of a set: $\overline{K}=\cap_{a>1}aK$ given $aK \subset bK$ if $a<b$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider a set $K$ with the property $aK \subset bK$ if $a<b$. It is true that $\overline{K}=\cap_{a>1}aK$? If it is not true in general, it is true in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Ideas: at least in $\mathbb{R}^n$, visually it really seems that it must be true, because $\overline{K}\subset aK \quad \forall a>1$, but then I would need to prove that statement, and I would need some help. If the topological space is a metric one, I would use the characterization of closure in termns of distance 0, but I am not sure of how to write it. I have the strong intuition that this result must be true, but I need help with how to write the formal proof.

Comment: How do you define $aK$?

Comment: @5xum $aK = \{ ak : k\in K}$

Comment: I would not expect this to be true unless $0$ is an interior point of $K\subset\Bbb R^n$

Comment: @FShrike Notice the property I imposed about the sets of the form $aK$. In particular 0 is indeed in $K$.

Comment: @user210089 OK, but how do you define it outside $\mathbb R^n$? What does $ak$ mean for two elements $a,k$ if $a,k$ are not from $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb R^n$, respectively?

Comment: @5xum I see, you are right, thanks for the comment. I was thinking of a vector space that is also a metric space, because I was wondering if the property could be proved in settings more general than $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @user210089 Then I suggest you add that into your question. The question should contain all information needed to answer it. Also, by "vector space that is also a metric space", do you also require the metric and vector structure to be somehow connected? Do you mean a normed vector space? Please add as much context as possible.

Comment: @5xum Ok, I will rethink what I want exactly and will make a new post.

Comment: @user210089 I suggest you add the link to the new post into comments here so people can find it. I'd appreciate it if you tag me as well.

Comment: @5xum New post done, this time I hopefully everything that needs to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by $\subset$, you mean "proper subset", then the requirement that if $a<b$, then $aK\subset bK$, can never be satisfied in $\mathbb R^n$.

Take any set $K$. It can be shown that if $K\subset 2K$, then $-K\subset -2K$ (proof below).

Now we have two options:

1. $1K\subset 2K$ **is not true**. In that case, it is clearly not the case that $aK\subset bK$ for all $a<b$ (the counterexample is $a=1, b=2$).
2. $1K\subset 2K$ **is true**. In this case, setting $a=-2, b=-1$ provides a counterexample, because $-2K\subset -K$ is not true.

---

***Proof that if $K\subset 2K$, then $-K\subset -2K$***:

From the premuse $K\subset 2K$, we know that

1. For every $k\in K$, there exists some $k'\in K$ such that $k=2k'$
2. There exists at least one $k_0\in K$ such that $2k_0\notin K$.

We can now prove that $-1K\subset -2K$:

1. Take any $l\in -K$. Then $l=-k$ for some $k\in K$. Therefore, there exists some $k'\in K$ such that $k=2k'$. However, that also means that $l=-2k'$ for some $k'\in K$, meaning that $l\in -2K$. So this proves that $-K\subseteq -2K$.
2. It is also clear that $-2k_0\notin -K$, but $-2k_0\in -2K$, which means that $-K\neq -2K$.

So, we now see that if $1K\subset 2K$, then $-K\subset -2K$.